# convex combination of scalars

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I have a set of scalars $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and a set of nonnegative scalars $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1$.  Let $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ denote the min and max of $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$, respectively.  Is it then true that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \lambda_i \in [\lambda_{\min}, \lambda_{\max}]?
$$

If so, how does one show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\alpha_i = 1$, we find:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{\text{min}} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\alpha_i \lambda_{\text{min}}
\end{equation}
If we now use that $\lambda_{\text{min}} \leq \lambda_i$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, we find
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\alpha_i \lambda_{\text{min}} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\alpha_i \lambda_i
\end{equation}
and after combining we find that 
$$ \lambda_{\text{min}} \leq  \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\alpha_i \lambda_i.$$

The same can be done for $\lambda_{\text{max}}$.